# Android - Rails communication

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the lack of information on the web ask a question: 
I'm going to create an application in Android, the use of a database application 
Rails. For this I need a manual session. So if anyone has a ready 
example / tutorial showing communication android-rails using 
session, or is able to share your knowledge on this subject?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by manual session, I communicate with my rails web app from Android via REST urls and XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 3 resources use RESTful APIs by default. Define a supported format (XML or JSON) in your Rails app and just make REST calls from your Android client.

There should be no need for you to be trying to manipulate the database directly from your Android client. That will skip all the validations and before_saves you have set up in your Rails app.

Use REST and you should be fine.

Comment: also, with direct database calls, you have to store your database user information in your android application, which isn't a good idea.